# Unable to get Sharepoint data using Postman

Tags: rest, sharepoint, postman

I am trying to fetch data from https://mysite.sharpoint.com, I am able to get data from chrome( for example, request to https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists) as my credentials are stored in Chrome. If I try to get the same request from REST client(Post man or ARC) or C#(HttpClient), I face 403 Forbidden error.

I followed steps given in http://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/, I am facing 403 Forbidden error at step 3 (Get the request digest).
I need to access data in share point online using REST api. Please share your suggestions.

NOTE:
I have following 3 inputs from user,

- Share point site URL
- Username
- password

Comment: Refer this link. This will work for you -- https://blog.sprider.org/2016/09/15/access-sharepoint-online-rest-api-via-google-postman-with-user-context/

Comment: @RohitWaghela Link is not working If you have some other link please share ...Thanku

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that everything runs smoothly until the "Get the request digest" request:

If you get a 403, the "Cookie" headers in your Postman "Get the request digest" request have the wrong values.

Make sure that the "Cookie" headers have the values from the "Set-Cookie" properties of your "Get the access token" response.